# subprocess.Popen and space character in the arguments

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, subprocess, osx-yosemite

I’m using Python 2.7 on OSX Yosemite to wrap a desktop app into a web application.

[The documentation says the following](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html):

> Providing a sequence of arguments is generally preferred, as it allows the module to take care of any required escaping and quoting of arguments (e.g. to permit spaces in file names)”

…and also

> the use of shell=True is strongly discouraged in cases where the command string is constructed from external input

That’s why I’m calling subprocess.Popen with long list of the arguments and shell=False

Regardless on what’s written in the documentation, I’m having problems passing arguments containing spaces.
In debugger after a fork I see my arguments go directly to os._execvpe without any changes/escaping.
Yet, the app I’m launching only receives the first space-delimited part of that argument.

Is there a way to fix subprocess.Popen so it works as documented? Thanks in advance.

P.S. Could it be because half of the arguments on my list are ASCII strings another half is Unicode strings?

**Update:** here's the Python code:

```
p = subprocess.Popen( arguments, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE )
```

And here's the truncated list of the arguments:

```
['/Library/WebServer/Documents/XXX.app/Contents/MacOS/XXX',
'-project', u'/Library/WebServer/Documents/XXX.YYY',
'-user', u'bec4aed7-2ee2-4ec9-0f92-a301ee9d0115',
'-log', u'/Library/WebServer/Documents/Users/bec4aed7-2ee2-4ec9-0f92-a301ee9d0115/renderLog.txt',
'-text', '1', u'one two three four']
```

The application only receives the first part of that u'one two three four' argument.

Comment: Show us the code of your Popen call and the argument list.

Comment: @miindlek done, please see an update.

Comment: What is `XXX.app`? Does it work properly with arguments that contain spaces?

Comment: It's a custom app. Yes, when launched from the terminal like XXX.app/Contents/MacOS/XXX -text 1 "one two three four" it works OK.

Comment: Try making a python program that simply does `import sys; print sys.argv` and see what happens when you call it.  (Worked for me fine with Ubuntu with your data.)

Comment: Hey, I know it's late but I'm having this exact issue and I'm not able to find the solution. Any ideas?

Comment: @entropy.maximum Please see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that worked for me was to convert all command-line arguments to Unicode, and escape them.

Here’s my escape method, note how it prepends spaces with backslashes:

```
@staticmethod
def _escape_string( val ):
    # Make unicode
    val = unicode( val )
    # Escape stuff
    val = val.replace( u'\\', u'\\\\' )
    val = val.replace( u' ', u'\\ ' )
    return val
```

After that change, my child process started to receive the complete strings.